# JavaScript API for Excel to get file size

Tags: excel, ms-office, office-js

I would like to know if there is an JavaScript API for Excel to tell the size of an Excel file.

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

No. The browser (including JavaScript)  don't access files on the clients computer i.e. Excel file. Upload the file to the back-end, and allow the server to analyse the file, and send result back to client/browser (JavaScript)